# XSLT library for v8/Node.js

Tags: node.js, xslt, v8

I found that there are some XML libraries available for v8/Node.js: http://github.com/ry/node/wiki/modules#parsers-xml

However, after drilling down into these modules, it seems that they only provide support for parsing XML documents, and manipulating them with DOM. I'm wondering if anyone is aware of an XSLT library for Node.js or v8.